# SwiftUI: Intermittent crash when tap on TextField

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

A few users of mine reported crashes when they tried to tap on a text field with custom style (nothing special about it) with auto-correction and auto-capitalization off. I cannot reproduce it, they cannot reproduce it either. There seem to be 2 particular text fields that cause the problem, both are contained in a bigger view presented with `fullscreenCover`. The crash log doesn't point to anything specific. Here is the crash log:

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   SwiftUI                         0x000000018e0c9154 CGRect.subscript.getter + 140 (Rect.swift:0)
1   SwiftUI                         0x000000018e0c9128 CGRect.subscript.getter + 96 (Rect.swift:0)
2   SwiftUI                         0x000000018d09ca98 $s7SwiftUI16IncrementalStackPA2A01_cD6_StateVyxG0E0RtzrlE5place8children7context5state2inyAA01_C15Layout_ChildrenV_AA01_cK17_PlacementContextVAFzAA01_cK11_PlacementsVztFAA010LazyHStackK033_00B4ADB3... + 304
3   SwiftUI                         0x000000018cfb477c specialized closure #2 in IncrementalChildPlacements.updateValue() + 396 (<compiler-generated>:0)
4   SwiftUI                         0x000000018d105b9c partial apply for closure #1 in _ViewCache.withMutableState<A, B>(type:_:) + 24 (IncrementalLayout.swift:1469)
5   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001839275b4 withUnsafePointer<A, B>(to:_:) + 20 (LifetimeManager.swift:144)
6   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000183afacac withUnsafeMutablePointer<A, B>(to:_:) + 12
7   SwiftUI                         0x000000018d0c7eb8 _ViewCache.withMutableState<A, B>(type:_:) + 236 (IncrementalLayout.swift:1466)
8   SwiftUI                         0x000000018d1e032c specialized IncrementalChildPlacements.updateValue() + 704
9   SwiftUI                         0x000000018d098808 partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 96 (<compiler-generated>:0)
10  AttributeGraph                  0x00000001aa5ae858 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 512 (ag-closure.h:109)
11  AttributeGraph                  0x00000001aa5ade50 AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 420 (ag-graph-update.cc:714)
12  AttributeGraph                  0x00000001aa5acc7c AG::Subgraph::update(unsigned int) + 828 (ag-subgraph.cc:734)
13  SwiftUI                         0x000000018cf825f8 ViewGraph.updateOutputs() + 216 (GraphHost.swift:640)
14  SwiftUI                         0x000000018cf8fc98 closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 2200 (ViewGraph.swift:592)
15  SwiftUI                         0x000000018d01be50 ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 360 (ViewRendererHost.swift:192)
16  SwiftUI                         0x000000018cf83d20 _UIHostingView.displayLinkTimer(timestamp:isAsyncThread:) + 244 (UIHostingView.swift:2109)
17  SwiftUI                         0x000000018cf81eac DisplayLink.displayLinkTimer(_:) + 308 (_UIHostingView.swift:883)
18  SwiftUI                         0x000000018cf83174 @objc DisplayLink.displayLinkTimer(_:) + 52 (<compiler-generated>:0)
19  QuartzCore                      0x000000018add6614 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 832 (CADisplay.mm:4507)
20  QuartzCore                      0x000000018ade7698 display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 368 (CADisplayTimer.cpp:219)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001849b1c34 __CFMachPortPerform + 172 (CFMachPort.c:586)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001849ccf04 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56 (CFRunLoop.c:1981)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001849cea30 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 512 (CFRunLoop.c:2120)
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001849b258c __CFRunLoopRun + 2324 (CFRunLoop.c:3175)
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001849b6b58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
26  GraphicsServices                0x00000001bf21f984 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2196)
27  UIKitCore                       0x000000018bc0d628 -[UIApplication _run] + 868 (UIApplication.m:3754)
28  UIKitCore                       0x000000018bc0d2a0 UIApplicationMain + 312 (UIApplication.m:5344)
29  SwiftUI                         0x000000018d106cfc closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 164 (UIKitApp.swift:37)
30  SwiftUI                         0x000000018d07d6a4 runApp<A>(_:) + 140 (<compiler-generated>:0)
31  SwiftUI                         0x000000018d069fe0 static App.main() + 96 (App.swift:114)
32  MyApp                       0x0000000102c95a44 static MyAppApp.$main() + 28 (MyAppApp.swift:10)
33  MyApp                       0x0000000102c95a44 main + 40 (MyAppClass.swift:0)
34  dyld                            0x00000001a653ddf0 start + 2096 (dyldMain.cpp:1170)
```

From this doc, it says that this is because of [force unwrap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-crashes-from-swift-runtime-errors). However, I use force upwrap very minimally. I check the `MyAppClass`, there is no force upwrap in it, I check a few places where I use force unwrap as well, nothing dangerous (I only use it for local vars and always check `!= nil` before doing `!`).

Here is the custom textfield style:

```
struct CustomTextfieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
  private let font: Font
  private let height: Double

  init(font: Font, height: Double) {
    self.font = font
    self.height = height
  }

  func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
    configuration
      .font(font)
      .foregroundColor(.white)
      .padding(.horizontal, 10)
      .frame(height: height)
      .background(MyShape())
  }
}
```

Comment: What is going on with the height? Why are you using underscores?

Comment: what do you mean? I set the height for the textfield, and the names with underscore are defined by `TextFieldStyle`

Comment: Dang, I have a stack trace in a complex app that looks just like this but unfortunately not using a TextFieldStyle and can't pin it to any particular text field. Feels like nothing to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unofficially, when there is an Apple `class`, `struct`, `func` that starts with an `_` the  item that is marked like that is "private/undocumented" and therefore unreliable.

https://forums.swift.org/t/make-it-official-the-undocumented-private-api-signifier/47381

`TextFieldStyle` seems to not provide any `public` versions of `body` and this implementation does not follow the pattern of others such as `ButtonStyle`, `ToggleStyle`, `GaugeStyle`, etc.

All these other styles use `func makeBody(configuration: Configuration)`.

I did not realize this when I made my initial comment.

What does this all mean?, you should not use `TextFieldStyle`. Instead you should create a subview will all the stylings and use that version.

The first line of the crash suggests that the crash is happening when getting the `CGRect`. If you aren't providing an invalid height like 0 or -1 on purpose or accidentally my guess is that `configuration` is providing an invalid `CGRect`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. Your observation might be right about the custom text field style. My first crash report was on the same build this custom style was first introduced.

Comment: Now you mention the underscore thing, implementing a custom text field style seems like a hack and we should not do that as you said. Confusing stuff, why Apple decide to make it this way. Anyhow, I will try to use custom view instead of custom style and if there is no more crash logged, I'll set this answer as accepted.
Thanks

Comment: Pushed a new build 3 days ago, no crashes so far. Making this the accepted answer.

Comment: The issue came back :sigh: